# Divisibility of a 7-digit number by 21

Tags: combinations, divisibility

How many *7-digit* numbers formed by using only the digits $3$ and $7$, and divisible by $21$ are there?

Well, I let the number be *abcdefg* and:

1. Placing $3$ at any position gives $0 \bmod 3$
2. Placing $7$ at all positions *a,b,c,d,e,f,g* gives $1 \bmod 3$

Then for *abcdefg* to be divisible by $3$, there would be $7C3 + 7C0 +7C6$ options

Next:

1. Placing $7$ at any position gives $0 \bmod 7$
2. Placing $3$ at $a$ gives $3 \bmod 7$, $b$ gives $2 \bmod 7$, $c$ gives $6 \bmod 7$, $d$ gives $4 \bmod 7$, $e$ gives $5 \bmod 7$, $f$ gives $1 \bmod 7$, $g$ gives $3 \bmod 7$

And then I was going to do the same thing as before but how do I sort of link it back to divisibility by $21$? Is it PIE or something? Any hint would be appreciated. Thank you.

Edit: Oops, I realised that I've solved it already. So I used the mod values for 7 obtained above and selected any 3 or 6 out of *a,b,c,d,e,f,g* , to take the value 3, that would add up to be divisible by 7 and since the sum of the digits would add up to 3, they would be divisible by 21 naturally. The combinations are (a,f,g), (a,c,e), (c,e,g), (b,d,f), (a,b,c,d,e,f) and (b,c,d,e,f,g). Therefore, the answer is 6 which is correct. But if anyone has any other solution that is simpler or more elegant, do let me know as well!

Comment: So the number has to be divisible by $21$, meaning that it has to be divisible by $3$ and $7$. A number is divisible by $3$ if and only if the sum of the digits is divisible by $3$. This means that there has to be either $0,3$ or $6$ 7's in the digits. Divisibility by $7$ is also relatively easy to check: You take off the last digit, add up the remaining digits and then subtract twice the last digit from the sum. If the answer is divisible by  $7$, then the original number is divisible by $7$. That means that
$$
a + b + c +d +e + f -2g 
$$
has to be divisible by $7$.

Comment: Oh wait, I think I've got (a,f,g), (a,c,e), (a,d), (d,g), (b,e), (c,f), (c,e,g), (b,d,f) as the possible places to place 3, while placing 7 in the remaining positions, would it be enough to just check each case for divisibility by 3?

Comment: Start with $3333333$, which is $1 \mod 7$ and $0 \mod 3$. You already know you have to replace $3$ or $6$ of those threes with sevens to keep it working mod $3$. What happens mod $7$ for each single digit replacement? Which combinations of three or six replacements will make it $0 \mod 7$?

Comment: @MattiP. You got your divisibility test for $7$ wrong. Your test makes for example $111$ divisible by $7$. The test should not use the sum of the leading digits, but the number formed by those leading digits and apply that recursively. E.g. $3024$, $302-8=294$, $29-8=21$, $2-2=0$.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis ah yes, you are correct. My mistake! So actually
$$
abcdef - 2g
$$
has to be divisible by 7.